# Switching from Android Gradle 7.4.2 to 8.0.2

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to switch my current project that uses 7.4.2 to AGP 8.0.2

I understand to use AGP 8.0.2 I need to have [JDK 17](https://developer.and**roid.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#jdk-17-agp), which I have done.

My app targets API 33, so my understanding based on information outlined [here](https://developer.android.com/build/jdks#compileSdk) is when building the app I should be using sourceCompatibility & targetCompatibility of JAVA_11

However that gives me errors like this:

```
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 11) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
```

However, if I change my sourceCompatibility & targetCompatibility to JAVA_17 everything works fine.

How do I keep my current target to Java 11 and still switch to using AGP 8.0.2? Or am I mis-interpreting the section **"Which Java APIs can I use in my Java or Kotlin source code?"** in above referenced Android documentation?